# how to use the same rpsec test case to test different site

Tags: rspec

I want to use the same rpsec testcase to test different websites, 
for example, I can test all the sites at one time, and also I can test one of them at one time.
would you mind give me some advise? how can I do it in a simple way.

I gem install rspec , not rspec-rails.
This is my code

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'net/http'
require 'json'
require 'uri'


describe 'mywebsite1' do
  uri = URI.parse('http://mywebsite1/')
  initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'}
  req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri, initheader)

describe 'common_test' do
  payload = JSON.parse(open("file.json").read)
  req.body = payload.to_json
  context 'case1' do
  res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
    http.request(req)
  end
  result = JSON.parse(res.body)
  it "should response with the code 201" do
    expect("#{res.code}").to eq '201'
  end
  specify "status is Ready" do
    expect(result['item']['status']).to eq 'Ready'
  end
  specify "type is All" do
    expect(result['item']['type']).to eq 'All'
  end
end
    context 'case2' do
    ...
    end
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `shared_examples_for` to reuse a set of examples between different specs, e.g.

```
shared_examples_for 'a website' do
  context 'case1' do
    let(:req) {
      Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri, {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
    }

    let(:res) {
      Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
        http.request(req)
      end
    }

    it 'should respond with 201' do
      expect(res.code.to_i).to eq(201)
    end
  end
end
```

Then when you want to use the shared examples you use `it_should_behave_like` and pass the name of the shared examples, e.g.

```
describe 'my website' do
  it_should_behave_like 'a website' do
    let(:uri) { URI.parse('http://mywebsite') }
  end
end

describe 'a different website' do
  it_should_behave_like 'a website' do
    let(:uri) { URI.parse('http://anotherwebsite') }
  end
end
```

You can see further details at https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/example-groups/shared-example-group

Comment: that's quite what I want to do, Thank you vvvvvvvvvery much